# trying to connect react native app to firebase using expo

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo

I am using expo "Bare workflow" in order to connect my react app to firebase.

This is what I have done so far following [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

1. I had an existing firebase project which I am trying to connect to.
2. I clicked on the android icon and registered the app also download the configuration part, I have even added Firebase SDK and applied the plugins, When I use

> var admin = require("firebase-admin");

then I get this error:

[image]

in my app/build.gradle I do get the following error at:

> import com.android.build.OutputFile

```
the error is: cannot resolve symbol "build"
```

how can I solve this ?

I also clicked on the file and pressed on invalidate/ cache restart, and I did that too when I click on run on my android studios on the edit configuration window that pops open it tells me `Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag`

when I click File->Project structure, there I see under project SDK that no SKD has been selected.

so I am not sure what is causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your Firebase instance, then go to the left side where it says "Real Time Database" and set that up. Make sure you have react-native-firebase installed (`expo install react-native-firebase`). Create a config.js file that looks like this:

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';
let config = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: ''
};
let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const db = app.database();
```

Fill this in with your information, which can be found in the firebase console after creating a web app for your firebase project. (`</>` button).

Now that you have your firebase linked to your expo project, import your database using `import { db } from '{path to your config file}';`

Let me know if you need help pushing and pulling data from your RTDB instance.